# How to prevent Redshift user copy or saving table data from the output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am working on Redshift database and want to stop user to save table data. Thay can see but can not copy or save table data. This is about security. Can someone please help me with any solution?
Also how can I access redshift database outside of remote desktop. Do I need shared subnet or something?

I tried to give read access to the user but could not stop to save tha data.

Answer (score 0):

If a user can view information on their computer, there's no real way to stop them saving that information. For example, they could use Copy & Paste or even take a screenshot of what is on the screen.

I once saw a "clean room" where Company A was providing services for Company B. Staff from Company A were allowed to access information about Company B's customers. To prevent them from taking/copying any information, all the computers in the room had their USB ports and CD/floppy drives removed/disabled. The computers were unable to access the Internet and they were all kept in a secure room. The idea was that staff from Company A would not be able to copy the information from the computers.

Unless you wish to go to similar lengths to protect information 'exfiltration', you need to live with the fact that information can be copied.

**Q: how can I access redshift database outside of remote desktop?**

Amazon Redshift can be accessed via JDBC/ODBC drivers. There is no requirement that a Redshift database can only be accessed via a Remote Desktop connection. Presumably, your company has provided a remote desktop with software installed that can connect to the database but this is not a restriction required by Redshift.

Accessing Redshift database requires network connectivity to the database, plus access credentials.